# how to build a super bag based on two sub-bags in Apache Pig on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Suppose I have two bags, B1 and B2, and wondering how to make a super bag contain the two bags? The purpose I want to have one super bag containing two sub-bag is because I want to call UDF SetDifference of datafu, which seems to be called on a relation which contains two bags?

In my case, I already have two bags, B1 and B2. I think I need to assemble a super bag "input" in this sample.

http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/guide/set-operations.html

```
differenced = FOREACH input {
  -- input bags must be sorted
  sorted_b1 = ORDER B1 by val;
  sorted_b2 = ORDER B2 by val;
  GENERATE SetDifference(sorted_b1,sorted_b2);
}
```

Update:

Here is my code and related error message, if anyone have any good ideas, it will be great.

```
register datafu-1.2.0.jar;
define setDifference datafu.pig.sets.SetDifference();

-- input1.txt: {(3),(4),(1),(2),(7),(5),(6)}
-- input2.txt: {(1),(3),(5),(12)}
A = load 'input1.txt' AS (B1:bag{T:tuple(val:int)});
B = load 'input2.txt' AS (B1:bag{T:tuple(val:int)});

sorted_b1 = ORDER A by val;
sorted_b2 = ORDER B by val;
differenced = setDifference(sorted_b1,sorted_b2);

-- expected produces: ({(2),(4),(6),(7)})
DUMP differenced;

[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <file TestDataFu3.pig, line 11> Cannot expand macro 'setDifference'. Reason: Macro must be defined before expansion.
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hadoop Pig UDF invocation issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429735/hadoop-pig-udf-invocation-issue)

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the same question?

Comment: @GoBrewers14, the issue is not resolved in my original question. My new issue is how to handle two bags as input, other than one super bag. Thanks.

Comment: DataFu's documentation is pretty clear about how to use `SetDifference()`, `SetUnion()` and `SetIntersection()`;  You take 2 bags and put them in the function.  There is no "super bag" in the link you provided (I don't know what a "super bag" is).  `B1` is a bag; `B2` is a bag;  put them in the function.  `input` is not a bag.  It is a relation that contains 2 bags.

Comment: @GoBrewers14, thanks for the comments. I have updated the answer and if you have any good advice, it will be great. :)

Comment: @GoBrewers14, with both my code to show my pain points and the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I see what you are asking; your bags are in different files.  You will need to import and then join them so that they are in the same relation.

**Script**:

```
REGISTER /path/to/jars/datafu-1.2.0.jar;
DEFINE SetDifference datafu.pig.sets.SetDifference();

data1 = LOAD 'input1' AS (B1:bag{T1:tuple(val1:int)});
data2 = LOAD 'input2' AS (B2:bag{T2:tuple(val2:int)});
A = JOIN data1 BY 1, data2 BY 1;
diff = FOREACH A {
  S1 = ORDER B1 BY val1;
  S2 = ORDER B2 BY val2;
  GENERATE SetDifference(S1, S2);
};
DUMP A;
```

**Output**:

```
({(2),(4),(6),(7)})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ GoBrewers14, could you explain what means JOIN data1 BY 1, data2 BY 1? Thanks.

Comment: When join two relations, you need join *BY* something -- a column that is common to both relations.  There is nothing common in `data1` and `data2` so I just put something there that would evaluate to `True` always.  Like using `(1=1)` in SQL.  http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#JOIN+%28outer%29

Comment: tested your code works for me, cool! Wondering what is the data format schema for A after join. It seems A is a bag, and it only has one record, the record has two fields B1 (a bag) and B2 (a bag), correct?

Comment: Ya its a bag.  If you need to know the schema of a relation use `describe`.

Comment: thanks and know how to use describe, and my question is A only has one row after join? Thanks.

Comment: `diff` is the new relation (in my example).  So type `DESCRIBE diff;`.  Again, all of this is in the `Pig` documentation http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html

Comment: did some debugging today and verified A only has one row. Thanks for all the help and mark as answered. BTW, wondering if you met with any related issue here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639554/how-to-remove-empty-deflate-files-for-a-hive-query :)