# How to avoid generating empty .deflate files for a Hive query?

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I run a Hive query, a large number of empty `.deflate` files are generated (they are actually about 8 bytes, which I think is the minimum size for a `.deflate` file).  I suspect this is happening because the query requires a large number of reducers.  I am wondering if there is a way to avoid generating these empty `.deflate` files?

Thanks in advance,

Lin

Comment: Does anyone have any comments? Thanks. :)

Comment: how about `rm *.deflate` ?

Comment: @GoBrewers14, :) I want to avoid generating them. Is there any settings in hive? Thanks.

Comment: Then your question is misleading/incorrectly worded.  The word "remove" suggest the existence of something.

Comment: @GoBrewers14, making sense, corrected the question and any insights are appreciated for this question. :)

Answer (score 10):

**`.deflate`** is the default **`compression codec`**

There are compression settings for **`Hive`** that can be used to reduce the amount of disk space that **`Hive`** uses for its **`queries`**.

When the property **`hive.exec.compress.output=true`**, `Hive` will use the **`codec`** configured by the **`mapred.map.output.compression.codec`** property to compress the storage in `HDFS`.  These properties can be set in the **`hive.site.xml`** or in the **`Hive-CLI`**.

To enable output compression from **`Hive-CLI`**.:

**`hive> set hive.exec.compress.output=true;`**

To enable output compression using **`hive.site.xml`**

```
<property>
 <name>hive.exec.compress.output</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>
```

So to disable the **`.deflate`** file:

set **`hive.exec.compress.output=false;`**

Comment: thanks for the response, and all the details. My question is not how to avoid generating .deflate files, but to avoid generating empty .deflate files, I found each reducer will generate a .deflate file, even if it is empty. Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Vinkal, if you have any thoughts how to avoid generating .deflate files, appreciate for your share. :)